# How to disable log4net.xml file generation

Tags: c#, log4net

I'm trying to use Log4net for my c# application. But when my application runs it generates log4net.xml file. As I read , It includes some information related to use in .NET documentation . But I no need this file or documentation.

How to disable log4net.xml file generation.

Comment: Are you using dll file or project of log4net?

Comment: yes I'm using log4net.dll. I'm directly download this DLL from Apache web site

Comment: Then I don't know why

Comment: If you are using log4net project from **NuGet**, remove **log4net.xml** file from the packages folder that was created by the **NuGet** (that file is under the /lib/<.net framework version>) and it will not get copied to your output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application is NOT generating this file. This file is part of the Log4Net project alongside with the assembly (`log4net.dll`) and the public debugging symbols (`log4net.pdb`). Those file are simply copied to your application's output directory. If you don't want to have them (even though it is strongly recommended to keep them), you could remove them from the source.

If on the other hand you downloaded the source code of Log4Net and compiled it yourself, then you could disable XML documentation generation in the properties of the project. In this case no `log4net.xml` file will be emitted.

Comment: +1, Thank you for your answer. Could you please explain what is the use of this xml file to DLL. In log4net website they recommended to use `signed  assemblies`. So I think If I build log4net myself, no more sign there in the final DLL. So what can be the drawback without signed DLL?

Comment: The XML file contains documentation of the methods and types contained in the DLL. So in addition to Intellisense in Visual Studio you get documentation and description of each method in the log4net assembly that you are using. As far as the assembly signing is concerned, well, if the assembly is not signed, someone can replace this log4net.dll in your website with an assembly with the same name but different implementation containing some Trojan or whatever and your application will happily load it and use it. If the assembly is signed, it is guaranteed that your application will only work

Comment: with the original assembly that you downloaded from a trusted provider.

Comment: Thank you, Can I sign DLL using my own key? because I need to avoid above documentation functionality(Specially xml file).

Comment: Yes, you can sign it with your custom key. This will guarantee that the assembly is coming from you, not from the authors of Log4Net but which should probably be fine for you. Unless, ... you are using some other 3-rd party component which depends on Log4Net. In this case this 3-rd party component won't work because it won't accept the your signature of the log4net assembly. It will only load the official, trusted assembly.

Comment: How to do that? do you know any reference?

Comment: Yeah, there are gazillions of references: https://www.google.com/#q=.net+how+to+sign+assembly

Comment: Darin Dimitrov: thank you for your valuable advice. I will try this way. I think it is suitable for what I need. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using log4net project from **NuGet**, remove **log4net.xml** file from the packages folder that was created by the **NuGet**(that file is under the /lib/<.net framework version>) and it will not get copied to your output.

Comment: If you restore the package (e.g. on a build server farm) or upgrade the package to a newer version, the log4net.xml file will be copied again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open command prompt as administrator

```
cd C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_64\log4net\1.2.10.0__692fbea5521e1304
```

2. Rename `log4net.dll` 64bit to `log4net64.dll`
3. Copy `log4net.dll` 32bit to folder
   `C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_64\log4net\1.2.10.0__692fbea5521e1304`